# xsd.exe generate proper type

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\xsd.exe"`

`/order /n:eDD.KlasyXML /c /language:CS`

to generate my C# code.

Woks pretty fine but my `xsd` files contains type definition for example :

```
  <!--==========================================================-->
  <!--===                    QuantityType                    ===-->
  <!--==========================================================-->
  <xs:simpleType name="QuantityType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <doc:description value="Quantity" />
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:totalDigits value="15" />
      <xs:fractionDigits value="3" />
      <xs:minExclusive value="0" />
      <xs:pattern value="[1-9]\d{0,14}" />
      <xs:pattern value="([1-9]\d{0,13}|0)\.[0-9]" />
      <xs:pattern value="([1-9]\d{0,12}|0)\.\d[0-9]" />
      <xs:pattern value="([1-9]\d{0,11}|0)\.\d\d[0-9]" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Element definition looks like this :

```
<xs:element name="Quantity" type="emcs:QuantityType"/>
```

But output in XML looks like this :

```
<q4:Quantity>2000.0000</q4:Quantity>
```

Is there any way to force xsd.exe to respect type definition and output xml in proper format like this :

```
<q4:Quantity>2000.000</q4:Quantity>
```

This is how I convert object to string :

```
public static string XMLToString<T>(this T toSerialize)
{
    StreamReader streamReader = null;
    MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
    try
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schema.Add("eDD.SchematyXML", "traderToEdd.xsd");

        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();

        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, toSerialize);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    finally
    {
        if ((streamReader != null))
        {
            streamReader.Dispose();
        }
        if ((memoryStream != null))
        {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

How add schema or namespace to this ?

Comment: The fraction digits in the schema is 3 and you are getting four digits.  It looks like you are no0t referencing the schema when you are writing the results.  The q4 namespace is an indication that the schema (or namespace) is not added properly to your xml writer.

Comment: How to add schema definition to XmlSerializer ?

Comment: The URL attribute in the xml file is the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I probably do something wrong but it don't work for me. I tried but whatever I done fails.
The solution was to use xsd2code. It can generate Fraction Digits Attribute and much more. Its not free but it is worth any penny.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).